# Is it OK for cats to eat centipedes?

Tags: cats, poison, insects

My cat keeps eating centipedes! He was rescued on the street and remains an outdoor cat and occasional hunter. Indoors I've seen him eat centipedes more than once and each time I wonder if I should intervene or how much I should worry about it.

I keep an eye on him afterwards and both times I've seen it, he acts normal...though each time he seems to have a little hard time chewing it up, seemingly swallowing it ASAP instead!

Aren't centipedes poisonous? Looks like these kinds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scutigera_coleoptrata He's a pretty tough cat, at 18lbs. and not far from feral, so it seems he's fine. Are centipedes in general dangerous for cats?